# How to use list comprehensions for this?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to take input of 2 numbers: the number of rows and the number of columns. I then want to use these to output a matrix numbered sequentially. I want to do this using a list comprehension. The following is a possible output.

```
>>>> my_matrix = matrix_fill(3, 4)
>>>> my_matrix
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

I am using the following code to output a sequentially numbered list:

```
def matrix_fill(num_rows, num_col):
     list=[i for i in range(num_col)]
     return (list)
```

I cannot, however, figure out how to make the sequential list of numbers break into the separate lists as shown in the output based on num_rows.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: For loops would come to mind. However, I want to do this using a list comprehension and no loops which I just cannot wrap my head around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need itertools for that. [The range function can take a step as a parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range). Like this:

```
def matrix_fill(rows,cols):
    return [[x for x in range(1,rows*cols+1)][i:i+cols] for i in range(0,rows*cols,cols)]
```

And then it works as expected.

```
>>> matrix_fill(3,4)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Let's break this down a little bit and understand what's happening.

```
>>> [x for x in range(1,3*4+1)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

So what we want to do is to get a new slice every four elements.

```
>>> [x for x in range(1,3*4+1)][0:4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> [x for x in range(1,3*4+1)][4:8]
[5, 6, 7, 8]

>>> [x for x in range(1,3*4+1)][8:12]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
```

So we want to iterate over the elements of the list`[x for x in range(1,3*4+1)]` of length "rows*cols" `( 3 * 4 )`, create a new slice every "cols" number of elements, and group these slices under a single list. Therefore, `[[x for x in range(1,rows*cols+1)][i:i+cols] for i in range(0,rows*cols,cols)]` is a suitable expression.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could explain what is going on in (x for x in range(1,rows*cols+1)][i:i+cols] for i in range(0,rows*cols,cols) because i'm sort of lost.

Answer (score 0):

Nest a list comprehension inside another one, use `itertools.count()` to generate the sequence:

```
import itertools

rows = 3
cols = 4

count_gen = itertools.count() # pass start=1 if you need the sequence to start at 1
my_matrix = [[next(count_gen) for c in range(cols)] for r in range(rows)]
print(my_matrix)
# prints: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]

# As a function
def matrix_fill(rows, cols):
    count_gen = itertools.count()
    return [[next(count_gen) for c in range(cols)] for r in range(rows)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used the `numpy` module, the method is extremely simple, with no list comprehension needed.

```
my_matrix = np.arange(1, 13).reshape(3,4)
```

Printing the variable `my_matrix` shows

```
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]]
```